# Are these different ways to soften legumes chemically?

Tags: food-science, beans, legumes

When I cook dried legumes (Like beans,chickpea, fava) and trying to soften them in a reasonable amount of time I think about three options, or mixing the three:

1. Soaking
2. Long time cooking or pressure cooking
3. Adding baking soda

I wanted to know if all of the the above are chemically the same? I have found some conflicting answers online.

P.s. I tend to think that all of the above are different because of the flavour differences, soaking for too long make the legumes taste sprouty and lose the uniqueness, and (I think) baking soda makes the legumes taste more flat...

Comment: Soaking for too long definitely transforms the bean into _something else_: the seed is about to become a plant.